# Network and Diagrams question

Tags: puzzle, word-problem

Please help me with the approaches to solve the questions given, I have shared my attempt at the bottom of the question, let me know where I am going wrong with my logics :-

[image]

---

My Attempt:-

**Question 1:-**  For truck , the time for each of the process would be be 3 times, Now since overhauling a vehicle as per question is given to be the longest duration from P-U :- I went on the following route P-Q-R-T-U = (8+10+17+9) * 3 = 132 hours

I am not sure why the question is asking minimum overhauling time, there is just one overhauling time as per my understanding

**Question 2:-**  Overhauling path should still remain the same as used in 1st question (i.e. P-Q-R-T-U) because that is still the longest duration path available from P to U, Price as per earlier rule for 2 wheeler should be:- [(8+10+17+9)*2 ]*100 = 8800 rupees

Now, price as per new conditions:-

- P->Q = 15*110 = 1650 rupees[ATQ, earlier PQ was taking 16 hours , but now the time has been reduced by 1 hour, also the price for the activity starting from P will get increased from 100 to 110]
- Q->R = 19*112 = 2128 rupees
- R->T = 33*100 = 3300 rupees
- T->U = 17*100 = 1700 rupees

therefore as per new conditions, total cost of overhauling is coming out to be 8778 rupees

I am getting an amount less than what was there as per earlier condition, where have I gone wrong in my process ?

**Question 3:-**

For 2 wheelers as per earlier conditions , the price of overhauling should have been :- (8+10+17+9) * 100 = 4400 rupees

As per new condition, the overhauling path should still remain the same and so must be the cost

---